# OpenGL ES why is my texture turned 180 degrees?

Tags: opengl-es, texture-mapping

i am drawing a texture on a simple plane. The renderingcode is basically this:

```
gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, _vertexBuffer);

gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, _textureBuffer);

gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, _vertexBuffer.capacity()/3);
```

With _vertextBuffer as

```
new float[] {
    0, 0, 0,
    0, height, 0,
    width, height, 0,
    width, height, 0,
    width, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0
};
```

where width and height are positiv values. _textureBuffer is

```
new float[] {
    0, 0,
    0, 1,
    1, 1,
    1, 1,
    1, 0, 
    0, 0
}
```

With this the texture is turned around and mirrored or turned around 180 degrees. what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the OpenGL texture coords convention is "upside-down" from normal conventions, to fix it, flip your t texture coords (0 -> 1, 1 -> 0).

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I fix it with: new float[] {
    0, 0,
    0, -1,
    1, -1,
    1, -1,
    1, 0, 
    0, 0
  }